# I'm doing desginer pdf viewer problem in c++ but in the code I can't understand one thing

Tags: c++

Hello I'm new at coding I want to make my career as a coder and a web developer this is my code please help me to understand how we get maxheight

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

    int main() {
        int height = -1,len,heights[26];
        string str;
        for(int i = 0; i < 26; i++)cin >> heights[i];
        cin >> str;
        len = str.length();
        for(int i = 0; i < len; i++){
            if(heights[str[i]-'a'] > height)height = heights[str[i]-'a'];
        }
        cout << len*height << endl;
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Are you trying to figure out the largest value in `heights`?

Comment: Please explain what this code is trying to do, what is your expected result, and what is the result this code produces and how it deviates from your expected result.

Comment: Did you try to find the problem with a debugger?

Comment: [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31816095/3422102)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.